# When I click anywhere in body toggle jQuery hide automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use show hide Slide toggle for hide my login panel.
When I click on LogIn button it shows and when I again click in logIn button it hides, but I want that when I click on logIn button it show and when I click anywhere in body it hide automatically.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.login-wrapper').slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a click event bound to the document object

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showmenu').click(function (e) {
        $('.login-wrapper').stop(true).slideToggle();
    });
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).closest('#showmenu, .login-wrapper').length) {
            $('.login-wrapper').stop(true).slideUp();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c6pSp/)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `.click` handler to the document level to slide up the `.login-wrapper`.

But when you use it like that then when `.login-wrapper` is opened by clicking on the button `#showmenu`, the click will be bubble up on the DOM tree and fire the click event at the document level as well which will close your `.login-wrapper` again eventually.

That's why you need to make use of `e.stopPropagation()` here to prevent bubble up the DOM tree so your `.login-wrapper` will not be closed if you click on the button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function () {
        $('.login-wrapper').slideUp();
    });
    $('#showmenu').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.login-wrapper').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8GUJN/)**

---

Based on your comment, you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).click(function () {
        $('.login-wrapper').slideUp();
    });
    $('#showmenu').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.login-wrapper').slideToggle();
    });
    $('.login-wrapper').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8GUJN/1/)**

Comment: ya it's working but it is hide when i click in my login panel
login-wrapper is my login panel 
i want that when i click in login botton its show div login-wrapper div and when i click in anywhere in page it hide but don't hide when i click in login-wrapper div